# How to iterate through multiple child nodes with same name in a json response using C# and assert right content

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

I am getting below response from a webservice .
I want to write a test for this using specflow , and C# Nunit framework

```
{
   "status": "Healthy",
   "results":    [
            {
              "name": "Microservice one",
              "status": "Healthy",
              "description": "Url check MSOneURI success : status(OK)"
            },
            {
              "name": "Microservice two",
              "status": "Healthy",
              "description": "Url check MSTwoURI success : status(OK)"
            },
            {
              "name": "Microservice three",
              "status": "Healthy",
              "description": "Url check MSThreeURI success : status(OK)"
              },
            {
              "name": "Microservice four",
              "status": "Healthy",
              "description": "Url check MSFourURI success : status(OK)"
              },
            {
              "name": "Microservice five",
              "status": "Healthy",
              "description": "Url check MSFiveURI success : status(OK)"
              }
                ]
```

}

This is how my feature file looks

```
@uService
Feature: Micro Service - health check
In order to perform health check 
As a service
I want to ensure downstream Micro Services are healthy 

Scenario Outline: [uService] Status of downstream microservices are healthy
Given health check micro service
When health check is performed      
Then <nameoftheservice> service returns correct description and status


Examples: 
| downstreamservice   | 
| Microservice one    | 
| Microservice two    | 
| Microservice three  | 
| Microservice four   | 
| Microservice five   |
```

I need help with writing the binding method for the Then step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could deserialize the JSON with the Newtonsoft.JSON package then iterate over the list of services with LINQ in order to do the comparison.

Something like:

```
class MicroserviceStatus {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Status { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}

class MicroserviceHealthCheck {
   public string Status { get; set; }
   public List<MicroserviceStatus> MicroserviceStatuses { get; set; }
}

var microserviceHealthCheck = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MicroserviceHealthCheck>(json);

bool anyNotHealthy = microserviceHealthCheck.MicroserviceStatuses.Any(i => i.Status != "Healthy");
```

I wrote this straight into the editor so it may not be exactly correct, and you should already have the types available for the deserialization already, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thank you Andrew Meservy